# Auto-fit fixed-width layout to screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I have a website with a fixed-width layout, and that cannot be changed easily. Its width is around 1300px, so it doesn't render well on a smaller screen.

I am looking for a solution to make the website looks good even on small screens. It should be possile, because if the user changes the browser zoom level to something like 75%, everything looks quite good. But I read that changing browser zoom level is not possible in JavaScript, and that the behaviour of this feature is not consistent across browsers.

Is there a standard solution (a library or something) to solve this problem?

Comment: You can do that with css: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp Add breakpoints for the sizes you want and override you css.

Comment: Yes I know this rule but I would have to change a lot of CSS attributes... is there not a solution to do this easily and in a way that works with all screen sizes, without changing much of the code? Like the zoom implemented in Chrome.

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1300px; initial-scale=0.75" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already put the tag "responsive" in your tags. This means you know that you want a responsive website.

You *could* create mediaqueries on specific width's and set the zoom property to a suitable value (but Firefox does not support this: http://caniuse.com/#search=zoom ; you can use transform: scale() as fallback).

EXAMPLE:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    zoom: 0.75;
    moz-transform: scale(0.75, 0.75);
  }
}
```

The best solution would be to create mediaqueries on specific width's and take the effort of changing the width's of the elements. I don't see why the width can't be changed easily.

EXAMPLE:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .myElement {
    width: 600px; /* whatever, maybe 100%? */
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! The "zoom" rule is what I was looking for. I really think that in my case this was the best solution: fast to implement and the result looks good.

Answer (score 1):

For a start include this `meta` tag to your page's `<head>`:

```
<meta viewport="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

The above will force the website to scale on mobile devices. But you need to do some more work using [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

You can create different rules for different screen sizes:

```
@media(max-width: 768px){
    /** Small Mobile Screens */
}

@media(min-width: 768px){
    /** Large Mobile Screens, tablets e.t.c */
}

@media(min-width: 992px){
    /** Desktops, Laptops */
}

@media(min-width: 1200px){
    /** Larger Screens (Desktops, Laptops, e.t.c) */
}
```

You can set the width of your page to a different size in pixels for every screen